# Need to send test emails from local PC

Tags: smtp

I am working on an ASP.Net web application that sends email, but doing this over the weekend from home and do not have access to my organization's smtp server for sending mail.  What are my options for sending test emails to myself through the app?  I've tried plugging in Google's smtp settings using my credentials and ssl port number, but when I do, I get the following exception in the event viewer:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: IOException 
Exception message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed. at system.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
```

at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

I'm wondering what options I have at this point.  Are there public SMTP Servers/services that can be used to send mail just to yourself?

Edit - I've tried some additional smtp based off of other posts here settings:

```
<network enableSsl="true" password="XXXXX" userName="XXXXX@gmail.com" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" />
```

but I'm still getting an exception, although a different one: Exception information:

```
    Exception type: SmtpException 
    Exception message: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Tricare.handlers.ContactUs.SubmitForm() in c:\TFS\Tricare\Upgrade-branch\Website\handlers\ContactUs.ashx.cs:line 201
   at Tricare.handlers.ContactUs.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\TFS\Tricare\Upgrade-branch\Website\handlers\ContactUs.ashx.cs:line 47
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://websocket.email does what you want and will accept emails without credentials and allow you to poll for test emails as they arrive.